# dpkg: error processing package hardening-includes

Tags: upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I updated Xubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and am now getting:

```
dpkg: error processing package hardening-includes
```

when I try to install/remove any apps.

I tried using the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to possibly finish any half downloaded files:

```
dpkg: error processing package hardening-includes (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lintian:
 lintian depends on hardening-includes; however:
  Package hardening-includes is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lintian (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hardening-includes
 lintian
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/hardening-includes*` and after `sudo dpkg purge hardening-includes`, if the purge is successful do `sudo apt-get install hardening-includes`, if the purge is not successful, try with `sudo dpkg purge --force-remove-reinstreq hardening-includes`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall hardening-includes` works?

Comment: I'll add an answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ask `apt` to reinstall the package (this will fix any missing file and it'll reconfigure it again):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall hardening-includes
```